# Summarise keys and values from all json objects using jolt

Tags: jolt

I have a JSON input jolt transformation

```
[
  {
    "System": {
      "Provider": {
        "Name": "Microsoft-Windows-Eventlog",
        "Guid": "{sdada}"
      }
    },
    "EventID": "3434",
    "EventData": {
      "SubjectUserSid": "3455",
      "SubjectUserName": "abc",
      "SubjectDomainName": "def",
      "SubjectLogonId": "e4545",
      "ObjectServer": "dggg",
      "ObjectType": "eet"
    }
  },
  {
    "System": {
      "Provider": {
        "Name": "Microsoft-Windows-Eventlog",
        "Guid": "{sdada1}"
      },
      "EventID": "3435"
    }
  }
]
```

As you can see Event data is present in the first JSON but not in the second JSON object in the array

My desired output is :

```
[
      {
        "winlog": {
          "provider_name": "Microsoft-Windows-Eventlog",
          "provider_guid": "{sdada}",
          "EventID": "3434",
          "event_data": {
            "SubjectUserSid": "3455",
            "SubjectUserName": "abc",
            "SubjectDomainName": "def",
            "SubjectLogonId": "e4545",
            "ObjectServer": "dggg",
            "ObjectType": "eet"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "winlog": {
          "provider_name": "Microsoft-Windows-Eventlog",
          "provider_guid": "{sdada1}",
          "EventID": "3435",
          "event_data": {
            "SubjectUserSid": null,
            "SubjectUserName": null,
            "SubjectDomainName": null,
            "SubjectLogonId": null,
            "ObjectServer": null,
            "ObjectType": null
          }
        }
      }
    ]
```

I want to event data key in both the objects with the value as null for the second object

```
[

  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "System": {
          "Provider": {
            "Name": "[&3].winlog.provider_name",
            "Guid": "[&3].winlog.provider_guid"
          }
    },

        "EventData": "[&1].winlog.event_data"
      }
    }
 }]
```

My output is

```
[ {
      "winlog" : {
        "provider_name" : "Microsoft-Windows-Eventlog",
        "provider_guid" : "{sdada}",
        "event_data" : {
          "SubjectUserSid" : "3455",
          "SubjectUserName" : "abc",
          "SubjectDomainName" : "def",
          "SubjectLogonId" : "e4545",
          "ObjectServer" : "dggg",
          "ObjectType" : "eet"
        }
      }
    }, {
      "winlog" : {
        "provider_name" : "Microsoft-Windows-Eventlog",
        "provider_guid" : "{sdada1}"
      }
    } ]
```

In short how to summarize keys for each array JSON

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you can put default values into the tree like this:

```
  {
    "operation": "modify-default-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "EventData": {
          "SubjectUserSid": null,
          "SubjectUserName": null,
          "SubjectDomainName": null,
          "SubjectLogonId": null,
          "ObjectServer": null,
          "ObjectType": null
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is the key-value pair under event data is not constant, that's why I want to pick all the keys from all key-value pairs under event data from all the JSON objects in an array